# Get context from Pod launched with Airflow KubernetesPodOperator

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow

We have some dags that launch pods using KubernetesPodOperator and I'm trying to get some information inside the pod, like dag_id, task_id, try_number, environment, etc.

I know that I can get this information from the context of the Airflow task (for example, kwargs on Python Operator) but I've been wondering, is there a way that I can get that context from the pod that was launched?

Thanks!

Comment: can't the context info can be passed on as config map or secret or labels using the operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a pretty good solution to this

I made a Custom Wrapper for the class KubernetesPodOperator and update the env_vars with the context of the Airflow Task

```
import airflow.configuration as config
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator as AirflowKubernetesPodOperator

class KubernetesPodOperator(AirflowKubernetesPodOperator):

    def execute(self, context):

        environment = config.conf.get('webserver', 'web_server_name')

        ti = context['ti']
        dag_id = ti.dag_id
        task_id = ti.task_id
        run_id = context['run_id']
        try_number = str(ti._try_number)

        labels = { 
            'ENVIRONMENT' : environment,
            'DAG_ID'      : dag_id, 
            'TASK_ID'     : task_id, 
            'RUN_ID'      : run_id,
            'TRY_NUMBER'  : try_number,
        }

        self.env_vars.update(labels)
        super().execute(context)
```

Comment: The `self.env_vars` is of type `Optional[List[k8s.V1EnvVar]] = None` so `update` won't work as it might be `None` or else a `List`.

Comment: On airflow 2.0 self._env_vars is a list but this works for airflow 1.X because self.env_vars is a dictionary. I write a function a few weeks ago to deal with the retro compatibility.